# Android Google Play Services error: didn't find class com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment on path dexpathlist

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I know this issue gets reported pretty frequently, and the simple, oft-recommended solution is to check how I'm referencing the google play services library. However, I'm pretty confident that I've got all my bases covered. I've literally lost sleep over this error, so any advice is certainly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

First, here's my stack trace:

```
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{raj.wifiapp/raj.wifiapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2063)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at raj.wifiapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5586)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    ... 12 more
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5111)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    ... 25 more
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/raj.wifiapp-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/raj.wifiapp-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
02-06 15:32:12.577: E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    ... 28 more
```

Here's my manifest:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="raj.wifiapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
     <permission
        android:name="raj.wifiapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="raj.wifiapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAaizOmaOj15uOjUmNA4OnowrOLv88_vKI" />
         
        <activity
            android:name="raj.wifiapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="raj.wifiapp.Tracker">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
            </activity>
          
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here's my layout:

```html
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="Switch views" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:text="Scan" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My reputation is less than 10, so I'm gonna post links to screenshots of my build path.

i.stack.imgur.com slash e9F9d.png

i.stack.imgur.com slash wESAc.png

i.stack.imgur.com slash Vb5Vc.png

Comment: What does your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: i'm on eclipse; isn't gradle an Android Studio thing?

Comment: What version of Google play services do you have? If you just started this project, I would suggest using Android Studio.

Comment: I did just start this project,and I'm using the newest version of the library (SDK Manager says it's Rev. 22). Is studio that much easier to work with than eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported by Google. Android Studio is the official IDE. Make the switch and I can help you get started.

Comment: Go ahead and get started here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: any luck ?same issue with me here..

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring because you have not added the Google Play Services library in your app project. Please follow the following [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828) to add Google Play Services in your app to get the Google Maps work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but by the looks of it, I have already followed every step of that tutorial. Is there a specific line of XML that I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
to your fragment.xml

And try using extend Fragment instead of extend SupportMapFragment

Comment: Tried it and it didn't change a thing. I really don't think it would help, though, because SupportMapFragment is meant for SDK versions 11 and under (and my min is at 12).

Comment: Make Sure that the play services libproject has to be imported onto the same physical drive as your project. (check the 'Copy projects into workspace' checkbox when you import)